# Need UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell to have Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, uicollectionview

Within my `UITableView` I have a section that is a single `UITableViewCell`. That cell has a `UICollectionView` that scrolls horizontally.

The `UICollectionViewCell` contains a `UIImageView`, with a `UILabel` below it, and a `UILabel` below that label. So these stack vertically.

The 2 labels will be a max of 2 lines. The `UIImageView` will be the same size always.

The label data will change so at some point in time there may be labels that just take up a single line, where as one cell may have labels that fill up the 2 lines.

I have tried added a height constraint for the `UICollectionView` but that is hitting an error currently.

Without that the labels get adjusted fine, but the cells that have higher label heights look to be pushed upward and not aligned with all the other cells.

I need the `UITableViewCell` & the `UICollectionView` heights to update dynamically so that my row of `UICollectionViewCells` stay aligned. Meaning, the images will stay aligned and the labels stay relatively aligned, if that makes sense.

For the `UITableViewCell` xib I have a label at the top, then below that is the `UICollectionView` that has top, leading, trailing, and bottom constraints with the height constraint that is connected to an outlet.

Please let me know if any other information is needed to help.

Here is what I have tried:

```
// For the UITableViewCell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? customCollectionViewCell {
        let collectionItem = UINib.init(nibName: "collectionItem", bundle: nil)
        cell.myCollectionView.register(collectionItem, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionItem")
                
        cell.myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.myCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.myCollectionView.reloadData()
        // This seems to be causing some issues..
        let height = cell.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        cell.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
        cell.myCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.myCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
                
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // The over all height shouldn't be more than this
    return 300.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // Ideally I would like to just use this vs. setting a height for the row
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

// For setting the UICollectionViewCell Height
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    guard let myData = //getMyData, (myData.count - 1) >= indexPath.row else {
        return CGSize.zero
    }
    
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionItem", for: indexPath) as? collectionItem else { return CGSize.zero }

    let theData = myData[indexPath.row]
    
    let h = calculateHeight(titleString: theData.title ?? "", subTitleString: theData.description ?? "")

    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return CGSize(width: 160.0, height: h)
}

func calculateHeight(titleString: String, subTitleString: String) -> CGFloat {
    
    let imageHeight: CGFloat = 160.0
    let spaceBetweenImageAndLabels: CGFloat = 4.0
    
    let titleHeight = heightForView(text: titleString, font: UIFont(name: "Font", size: 14.0)!, width: 160.0)
    let subTitleHeight = heightForView(text: subTitleString, font: UIFont(name: "Font", size: 12.0)!, width: 160.0)
    
    let height = imageHeight + spaceBetweenImageAndLabels + titleHeight + subTitleHeight
           
    return height
}

func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

}

Comment: Send the calculated height from sizeForItemAt method for collectionview and use greater than or equal to constraints for the padding to center your cells in collectionview

Comment: Any additional context on how I can send the calculated height?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm to this protocol UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, along with Datasource and Delegate. Now implement the sizeForItemAt method for any cell using the indexpath. Calculate the label height here using the data and your expected width of cell.

Comment: I am doing this, but it's still causing issues as described above. This is in the code example above.

Comment: The problem I am having is if there is a cell where one of the labels is higher than all the rest then that one cell looks to expand more than the others. so when you look at the top it goes above the others. They should all have the same padding at the top. The difference should show when the table cell / collection view height changes & the labels will extend downward.

Comment: To clarify one thing, the cell should expand. But it's seems to be expanding at the top & bottom. I just need it to expand downward. So the table view row would expand along with the collection view & the labels would just extend downward.